How to debug connection drops between macOS host and Linux guest?
I run a Fedora Server VM on macOS Sonoma via UTM. UTM is configured to use a shared network, which creates a VLAN the VM joins and through which the host OS can discover it.
This all works fine, but in what appears to be random intervals, all network connections from macOS to the VM suddenly drop and remain broken. The only "fix" I have found is to reboot the VM, which returns everything to a working state. Since I SSH into the VM to perform work, this usually surfaces as request timeouts with SSH becoming unresponsive. Even pings to the VM will fail.
I suspected a routing issue (perhaps with the route dropping out of macOS's routing table?) but cannot find any evidence. The problem is that I don't know enough about networking internals, especially not with virtualization tech in between. This means I am currently "streetlighting" this problem because I don't even know where to look.
Could someone point me in the right direction here? Some facts below.
On the host
The VM hostname is work, IPv4 address is 192.168.64.2. I don't think it's a problem with IP lease because even after connections fail, it remains to have the same IP.
Pings and traceroutes to the VM will now fail:
$ traceroute 192.168.64.2

traceroute to 192.168.64.2 (192.168.64.2), 64 hops max, 40 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  *^C

$ ping 192.168.64.2

PING 192.168.64.2 (192.168.64.2): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3

The routing table looks OK though, AFAICT:
$ netstat -rn -f inet


Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags               Netif Expire
default            192.168.178.1      UGScg                 en0
default            link#24            UCSIg           bridge100      !
127                127.0.0.1          UCS                   lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH                    lo0
169.254            link#15            UCS                   en0      !
192.168.64         link#24            UC              bridge100      !
192.168.64.1       62.3e.5f.73.14.64  UHLWI                 lo0
192.168.64.2       8a.c3.94.a.86.e2   UHLWIi          bridge100   1199
192.168.178        link#15            UCS                   en0      !
192.168.178.1/32   link#15            UCS                   en0      !
192.168.178.1      dc:15:c8:ef:b8:1d  UHLWIir               en0   1198
192.168.178.52/32  link#15            UCS                   en0      !
224.0.0/4          link#15            UmCS                  en0      !
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI                en0
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWIg         bridge100
255.255.255.255/32 link#15            UCS                   en0      !

And when I drill into this specific route:
$ route get 192.168.64.2


   route to: work
destination: work
  interface: bridge100
      flags: <UP,HOST,DONE,LLINFO,WASCLONED,IFSCOPE,IFREF>
 recvpipe  sendpipe  ssthresh  rtt,msec    rttvar  hopcount      mtu     expire
       0         0         0         0         0         0      1500      1200

Bridge network interface (this is created by UTM as part of the VLAN I believe?)
ifconfig bridge100


bridge100: flags=8a63<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,ALLMULTI,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    ether 62:3e:5f:73:14:64
    inet 192.168.64.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.64.255
    inet6 fe80::603e:5fff:fe73:1464%bridge100 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x18
    inet6 fd5d:9cb:9b9e:3946:141b:1dc6:2328:9f96 prefixlen 64 autoconf secured
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x0
    member: vmenet0 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 23 priority 0 path cost 0
    Address cache:
        8a:c3:94:a:86:e2 Vlan1 vmenet0 1199 flags=0<>
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active

ARP lookups seem to work:
$ arp work


work (192.168.64.2) at 8a:c3:94:a:86:e2 on bridge100 ifscope [bridge]

On the guest
I couldn't see anything out of the ordinary here either.

So bridge100 on the host is enp0s1 on the guest and it is UP.
I started looking for NetworkManager entries in journalctl as well, but since I don't really know what I was looking for I wasn't sure what to focus on.
I'd appreciate any help.

Have you ever solved this ? (I have similar issues)

I haven't, but I have come closer to finding the cause: I now suspect it is a problem with the physical network connection and packets getting lost that somehow screw up the connection. The reason is that I happened to notice that when I'm on WiFi, it happens much much less frequently than when plugged into Ethernet over my USB/Thunderbolt hub. Like, twice a week on Wifi versus 2-3 times a day. So it's much more stable on WiFi. It's not the hub though; plugging LAN cable into the TB port on the macbook directly also makes the connection less stable again. It's all very strange indeed.

That said, however, I am no closer to a solution.

I also ran iperf between host and guest multiple times, to test for packet loss, but it never detected any. So maybe this is just another red herring.

The wifi / ethernet thing may be a good clue. I also have an external USB-C dock wich has an ethernet port that is never actually plugged in. I have also noticed that sometimes it doesn't crash for long periods and I now think this is when it is exclusively on wifi and not plugged into the USB-C dock. Maybe the problem happens when MacOS tries to make this dead ethernet interface available to the Linux guest repeatedly.

Maybe that was another red herring. I just had two connection drops again even on WiFi: first when coming back from suspending the laptop over lunch, then again completely randomly only 5 minutes later.

PS: I also cross-posted this question to https://serverfault.com/questions/1166754/how-to-debug-connection-drops-between-macos-host-and-linux-guest but also haven't really gotten any responses over there. But it contains more detailed logs of tests I have run so far. But none helped pinpoint the issue.
